# How to Return Counts of Values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, classification

I have a dataframe that contains a unqiue IP, and a Severity rating based on a scan result classifier, as shown:

[image]

My objective: for each unique IP, how do I return a count for each Severity level?  The goal is to ultimately create a table that lists each IPs totals for each level of Severity.

[image]

I already know how to get hits for the Totals column. That is as simple as:

```
df_IP_counts = df['IP'].value_counts()

or 

df_Severity_counts =df.Severity.value_counts()
```

But how to separate each individual IP's counts for CRITICAL, HIGH, MODERATE, and LOW is giving me trouble at the moment.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the actual data instead of an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call `groupby` + `count` -

```
result = df.groupby(['IP', 'Severity']).Severity.count().unstack()
```

To get the total count, you can call `sum` on the values and use `assign`/`concat`/inplace assignment to add it to the `result` dataframe -

```
result['Total'] = result.values.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Great. Now I just need to make sure the Totals column is included in the final result!

Comment: @TheHolyDarkness You can do `result.sum()` and concatenate that with the original result.

Comment: Nah. That leads to a result like 

[Severity
CRITICAL    219.0
HIGH        306.0
LOW          32.0
MODERATE    339.0]

This is the wrong output.

Comment: @TheHolyDarkness Ah, my bad. Try `result.values.sum()` :)

Comment: Yeah, I was beginning to think the same thing. However, due to the presence of nan values, it's still wonky.  How to transform nans into 0s again?

Comment: @TheHolyDarkness You can use `df = df.fillna(0)`. If you're working with arrays, use `arr[np.isnan(arr)] = 0`

Comment: That's closer to where we're going! Now, just to add the table...

I'm leaning on final_results = result.assign(Total = result.values[].sum()) but I don't want to use a while loop to iterate through the values[] array if I can help it. 

For instance, if I say values[0] it'll just return the first sum. If I say values[1] it'll return the second part. Surely there's a way to do this in one line...or maybe I'll just make a while loop I suppose lol.

Comment: @TheHolyDarkness Use the `axis` parameter - `results.values.sum(axis=0)` (or `axis=1`, I'm not sure, use whichever works.)

Comment: @TheHolyDarkness Don't forget to vote on, and mark the answer accepted if it was useful to you. Thanks.